# graphical representation

Tags: google-bigquery

The big query demo found on qlikview seems very interesting.

http://ap.demo.qlikview.com/QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=qvdocs/American%20Birth%20Statistics.qvw#

But I did not understand how do I apply this view to my tables.
Is there a software that needs to be installed in order to have such nice views?

Do I need to download QlikView Connector for Google BigQuery ?
I downloaded it along with QlikView Extension for Google BigQuery. But could not install it.
Is this installation really necessary or I can do it online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use QlikView and BigQuery together (via the "[QlikView Connector for Google BigQuery](http://market.qlikview.com/qlikview-connector-for-google-bigquery.html)"):

1. Download and install QlikView.
2. Download and install the QlikView Connector for Google BigQuery.
3. Visit "https://developers.google.com/console," select the BigQuery project you are working with, and under ***API Access*** create a ***Client ID for installed applications***.
4. Go back to QlikView and under ***File*** select ***Edit Script***
5. Under the *Data* tab at the bottom, select the *BigQuery* option from the dropdown menu.
6. Use the Client ID and Secret you created in step 3 in the dialog (make sure you have a web browser open, with a project member authenticated for Google Services).
7. You can then add your SQL-like BigQuery statement to the script editor.

There's more information available in the documentation that comes with the QlikView Connector for Google BigQuery.

Comment: Which qlikView license is required? (budget estimate...)

Comment: You can use the QlikView free version with the BigQuery connector. But for questions like this, I suggest you visit the QlikView website and go from there.